# select first nth percent of rows from random sampled dataframes of list in r

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I wrote a function that selects first nth percent of rows (i.e., threshold) from dataframe and this works on dataframes of list as well. The functions is given below:

```
set.threshold.rand <-function(value, vector){
  print(length(vector))
  n<-as.integer(length(vector)/100*value)
  threshold<-vector[n]
  return(threshold)
}

sensitivity.rand<-function(vector, threshold){
  thresh<-set.threshold.rand(threshold, vector)
  print(thresh)
  score<-ifelse(vector<=thresh, "H", "L") # after taking the threshold values it assign them to 'H' and 'L' according to condition
  return(score)
}
```

This function selects first nth percent of rows from dataframes of list. For example, the codes below selects first 143 rows as "H" which was expected.

```
vec.1 <- c(1:574)
vec.2 <- c(3001:3574)
df.1 <- data.frame(vec.1, vec.2)
df.2 <- data.frame(vec.2, vec.1)

my_list1 <- list(df.1, df.2)
my_list1 <- lapply(my_list1, function(x) {x[1] <- lapply(x[1], sensitivity.rand, threshold = 25) 
x})
```

But this don't work on sampled and replicated dataframes of list (given below). For example:

```
my_list <- replicate(10, df.1[sample(nrow(df.1)),] , simplify = FALSE)

my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {x[1] <- lapply(x[1], sensitivity.rand, threshold = 25) 
x})
```

These select more than 300 number of rows. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from answer given by #SirSaleh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306572/conditionally-assign-first-nth-element-in-vector-as-h-and-rests-as-l/43306664?noredirect=1#comment73689022_43306664):

```
sensitivity.rand <- function(vector, threshold){
  num_to_thres <- floor(threshold*0.01*length(vector))
  l = length (vector)
  score = c(rep("H",num_to_thres),rep("L",l-num_to_thres))
  return(score)
}
```

Now it can take any threshold and works with great efficacy.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `set.threshold.rand` relies on the fact that the input vector is sorted.

That's why it works with `my_list1` and not with `my_list`, where you've shuffled the rows with `sample()`.

Replace `threshold <- vector[n]` with `threshold <- sort(vector)[n]` in `set.threshold.rand`

Comment: If I use `threshold <- sort(vector)[n]` in `set.threshold.rand` it sorts values in `my_list` from lower to upper and takes first 25 percent as "H" (i.e., 1-143 has got "H"). But I wanted to have first 25 percent as "H" in the sorted dataframe (whatever values come in the first 25 percent rows will have "H"). How to solve this?