# assign first 25 percent of rows as T and others as F from dataframes of list

Tags: r, list, if-statement, dataframe

I have a list of randomly sampled rows of dataframes in list. I would like to assign the first 25 percent of rows in all dataframe as T and other rows as F. For example:

```
vec.1 <- c(1:574)
vec.2 <- c(3001:3574)
df.1 <- data.frame(vec.1, vec.2)
df.2 <- data.frame(vec.2, vec.1)

my_list <- replicate(10, df.1[sample(nrow(df.1)),] , simplify = FALSE)
```

In this list of dataframes I would like to assign the first 25 percent of rows as F and all other rows as T. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write a function like the following to be used within `lapply`:

```
myFun <- function(indf) {
  indf$vec.3 <- seq_len(nrow(indf)) <= .25*nrow(indf)
  indf
}
```

Usage would then just be `lapply(my_list, myFun)`.

Comment: Thank you. This function adds a new column. I don't want to add a new column. But I wanted to apply this on all existing columns or column 2 to 4 if there is more columns. Would you please add more comment on this?

Comment: @AnwarHossain, sure. Provide some reproducible input **and** desired output and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Note also that after creating the extra column, you can just `split` the data if you wanted them in different `data.frame`s.

Comment: Thank you. Idea on your second comment is good, but given the size of my data that will give lots of extra work. Would you please see this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175618/select-first-nth-percent-of-rows-from-random-sampled-dataframes-of-list-in-r)? I got one comment there but that didn't solve the issue. It would be better to edit that function or make new function that would work like that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @AnwarHossain, what are you trying to do exactly? For example, after getting your "T" and "F" or your "H" and "L", what do you plan to do with that? Also, have you considered  using `data.table` if your concern is about efficiency with large data?

Comment: I have a column for species name and other multiple columns (about 9). I will take H or L for 25 percent rows (i.e. 25 % species will get H and others will get L). For another list I will have different column numbers (about 4) and will do the same. If u can solve my previous question in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175618/select-first-nth-percent-of-rows-from-random-sampled-dataframes-of-list-in-r) that would be good. So that my code would be `my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {x[1:2] <- lapply(x[1:2], sensitivity.rand, threshold = 25) 
x})`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141271/discussion-between-anwar-hossain-and-a5c1d2h2i1m1n2o1r2t1).

Answer (score 2):

Guessing this is the beginning of a cross-validation approach you can do the following using the `modelr`-package

```
require(modelr)
dat <- crossv_mc(df.1, 10, test = 0.25)
```

Now dat looks as follows:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
            train           test   .id
           <list>         <list> <chr>
1  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>    01
2  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>    02
...
10 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>    10
```

So you have one column train holding 75% of the data and another column test holding the test data. This is equivalent to your `FALSE`/`TRUE` split.

You can work with this as follows (adopted the example from `?crossv_mc`)

Assign a new column holding the model:

```
dat$mod <- lapply(dat$train, function(x){
  lm(vec.1 ~ vec.2, data = as.data.frame(x))
})
```

the important part is: `as.data.frame(x)`. Use it if you want to access your data. See `?resample`.

Run some statistic on the model with the test data:

```
mapply(rmse, dat$mod, dat$test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306572/conditionally-assign-first-nth-element-in-vector-as-h-and-rests-as-l/43306664?noredirect=1#comment73689022_43306664) from answer of #SirSaleh.

```
sensitivity.rand <- function(vector, threshold){
  num_to_thres <- floor(threshold*0.01*length(vector))
  l = length (vector)
  score = c(rep("T",num_to_thres),rep("F",l-num_to_thres))
  return(score)
}
```

And now it is suitable to take any threshold.